# Show $P \vdash \sim \sim P$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

An excercise of my book asks me to prove that $P \vdash \sim \sim P$ by means of Łukasiewicz's axiom system. I've been able to show that $\sim\sim P \vdash P$, yet this doesn't seem to be of any help.

---

The axioms, as defined in my book (Logic for Philosophers), are all substitution instances of:
$$(p\rightarrow(q\rightarrow p))$$
$$(p\rightarrow(q\rightarrow r))\rightarrow((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow (p\rightarrow r))$$
$$(\sim p \rightarrow \sim q)\rightarrow ((\sim p \rightarrow q)\rightarrow p)$$

The only rule of inference is Modus Ponens.

Comment: Mind sharing the original book? According to wikipedia Łukasiewicz's axioms include $\lnot \lnot P \vdash P$. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%81ukasiewicz_logic).

Comment: Are you allowed to use deduction theorem? Deduction theorem says that if $A \vdash B$ is provable then $\vdash A \to B$ is provable.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it, but I am. The issue is that I don't see how it could be applied to the problem, since we would first need to have $P \vdash \sim\sim P$ in order to then use the theorem, unless you have something else in mind.

Comment: Oh I see how it could be used. Starting from $\sim\sim\sim P \vdash \sim P$ (what I had already proved) one can use the Deduction Theorem to then have $\vdash \sim\sim\sim P \rightarrow \sim P$. By using the third axiom and Modus Ponens one arrives at $(\sim\sim\sim P \rightarrow P)\rightarrow \sim\sim P$. By the first axiom we have $P\rightarrow (\sim\sim\sim \rightarrow P)$, and thus by using $P$ as a premise and Modus Ponens we have $\sim\sim\sim P \rightarrow P$ which finally gets us to $\sim\sim P$.

Comment: I presume these are exercises $2.11$ c) and d) of Theodore Sider's [*Logic for Philosophy*](https://epdf.pub/logic-for-philosophy.html).  In constructing three of the tools in the "toolkit" you're allowed to use—namely, "contraposition 2", "negated conditional" and "excluded middle MP"—Sider *assumes* that the theorem schema of these two exercises had *already* been established. Thus, if you use any those tools to do exercise $2.11$ c) or d), the argument would end up being circular. From your nice deduction of $\ P\vdash\sim\sim P\ $, I'm guessing you haven't actually done this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the best known Łukasiewicz's axiom system has $(\neg q \to \neg p) \to (p \to q)$ as an axiom in place of your third.

Fortunately, you can easily show $\vdash (\neg q \to \neg p) \to (p \to q)$ using your $(\neg p \to \neg q)\to((\neg p \to q)\to p)$:

Start with $\neg p \to \neg q$ and $q$. By axiom 1, you have $q \to (\neg p \to q)$, and so by MP: $\neg p \to q$, and now it is two MP's with your Axiom 3 to get $p$.

So, we have $\neg p \to \neg q, q \vdash p$, and thus by the Deduction Theorem $\neg p \to \neg q \vdash q \to p$

With that, and with your already shown $\neg \neg p \vdash p$ it's trivial, as by the Deduction Theorem you get $\vdash \neg \neg \neg p \to \neg p$, and with this axiom 3 you have $(\neg \neg \neg p \to \neg p) \to (p \to \neg \neg p)$, so a simple MP gives you $p \to \neg \neg p$