# Show $P, Q \vdash P \wedge Q$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm asked to show that $p, q \vdash p \wedge q$. Technically what must be shown is that $p, q \vdash \sim (p\rightarrow \sim q)$, since $\sim$ and $\rightarrow$ are taken as primitives. As axioms, I'm allowed to use all substitution instances of:

$$p \rightarrow (q\rightarrow p)$$
$$(p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow r))\rightarrow ((p\rightarrow q)\rightarrow (p\rightarrow r))$$

$$(\sim p \rightarrow \sim q)\rightarrow((\sim p \rightarrow q)\rightarrow p)$$

and only Modus Ponens as a rule of inference.

However I'm also allowed to use the Deduction Theorem, as well as $$p\rightarrow q, q\rightarrow r \vdash p\rightarrow r$$
$$p, \sim p \vdash q$$
$$\sim p \rightarrow \sim q \vdash q\rightarrow p$$
$$p \rightarrow q \vdash \sim q \rightarrow \sim p$$
$$\sim (p\rightarrow q)\vdash p$$
$$\sim (p\rightarrow q)\vdash \sim q$$
$$p\rightarrow q, \sim p \rightarrow q \vdash q$$

(I'm being somewhat informal in writing $\{a, b\} \vdash c$ as $a, b \vdash c$.)

---

I've been stuck on this exercise for more than an hour now and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know from [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3397565/show-p-vdash-sim-sim-p) that you have shown $\neg \neg p \vdash p$

So, since you can easily show that $p, p \to \neg q \vdash \neg q$, you can use the fact that $\neg \neg p \vdash p$ to show that $p, \neg \neg (p \to \neg q) \vdash \neg q$. Thus, by the Deduction Theorem, you have $p \vdash \neg \neg (p \to \neg q) \to \neg q$.

Likewise, since it is trivial to show that $q, p \to \neg q \vdash q$, we also know that $q, \neg \neg (p \to \neg q) \vdash q$, and use the Deduction Theorem to obtain $q \vdash \neg \neg (p \to \neg q) \to q$.

So, starting with both $p$ and $q$, we can obtain both $\neg \neg (p \to \neg q) \to \neg q$ as well as $\neg \neg (p \to \neg q) \to q$, and then combine that with the following instance of Axiom 3:

$(\neg \neg (p \to \neg q) \to \neg q) \to ((\neg \neg (p \to \neg q) \to q) \to \neg (p \to \neg q)$

to obtain:

$\neg (p \to \neg q)$